# Codename One issue: What will happen to the push notification service in an iOS app after expiration of a Codename One pro account subscription?

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications, codenameone

I need to develop the app in iOS as well as in Android using the Codename One framework. The app needs the push notification feature too. I see for Android I can get the push notification feature easily with a free account which was created from the Codename One website, but for iOS I say there is a need of professional Codename One account.

My office team is planning to sign up for the professional Codename One account for one month. After I subscribed with that pro account I can generate a iOS app with the push notification feature, and it will be also deploy in app store and can be installed in Apple devices.

After the expiration of the Codename One professional account, will an iOS app still be able to send/receive push notifications that have been already deployed in the app store, or do we just need a pro account for the compile time only? Or do we need to renew every time to get that push notification service? What will happen to the push service if I don't renew the pro subscription to an already deployed app in the app store after a few months?

Comment: Are you taking about the FCM notification service provided by Google or any other one?

Comment: You can't pay for the Apple Developer program on a month-by-month basis. You need to pay annually.

Answer (score 3):

The Codename One push servers will no longer accept your push requests but the app will keep working as usual it just won't get new push notification messages.

Answer (score -1):

If your Apple Developer Program membership expires, your apps will no longer be available for download and you will not be able to submit new apps or updates. You will lose access to pre-release software, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and Technical Support Incidents. However, your apps will still function for users who have already installed or downloaded them, and you will still have access to App Store Connect and free development resources.
If your Apple Developer Enterprise Program membership expires, your apps will no longer be available for download and will no longer function for those who have already installed or downloaded them. You will still have access to free development resources.

Reference link: https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

Comment: Thank you very much for this info . I am actually new to iOS and I have so many doubt about it.   The information you shared is also very useful for me and I am ready thankful for the reply.

Comment: Actually I am.using codenameone framework of java from where it allows us convert java code to Android as well as iOS. But there is limited function in free account and encourages  to go to proaccount for additional features.. if have any information about  codename one proaccount expiration in realed to push function please help me again. Thank you